# Google Drive API Service Account Authentication fails

Tags: https, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm using a service account ( with wide delegation) to manage different google services for a group of users (impersonating them).

Now i'm trying to load some attachment on Google Drive

(through  to this End Point (using Postman) -> POST.  https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media )

but I get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                "locationType": "header",
                "location": "Authorization"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Invalid Credentials"
    }
}
```

I added the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' in the Token and in the service account (through the Google Admin Console) as well.
I have also enabled the Google Drive Api on the Google Cloud Console.

I still getting this error. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem..... I was wrong the authentication token